# Find element feature

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I want to write ie based web developer tool with find element feature. i am using c# and wpf and my application should looks like ie developer tool:
[image]

or firebug:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: IE8 has built-in dev tools, but you have two choices. One, host IE (webbrowser control) in your app, and access/modify the DOM object from the webbrowser control. Two, create an IE plugin. Any more ideas which way you want to go?

Comment: Suggestion: ask a real, **specific** question that can be answered.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not start writing HTML parser.

Comment: I want host webbrowser control in my own application, but i donnt know how i can implement find element feature.

Comment: You hook into the mouseover event in the browser, grab the underlying element and modify the style.

Comment: WebBrowser doesnt has the mouseover event. Other events(mousemove for example) donnt get information about underlying element.

Comment: Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NetHtmlEventHandler.aspx

You can hook into events, but you need to code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To consolidate a bunch of answers:

You can either:

- Host IE in your app
- Make an IE plugin

To highlight an area, you should look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NetHtmlEventHandler.aspx